# Sum by unique ID and auto-deletion

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to achieve several targets at once. Please take a look at the original data sample:

**Original Data Sample**

[image: Original Data Sample]

What I intend to do is: going through every Unique ID in column A, as far as reaching a different UID, the last row belonging to the previous UID will be returning a sum of total numbers recorded for that UID in each column, and all rows except for the summary row will be deleted.

By my current code, my intended effect (partial as my final goal) should look like this:

**Partial Demonstration**

[image: Partial Demonstration]

At the end, after the deletion, the code should look like this:

**Final Affect Demonstration**

[image: Final Affect Demonstration]

My code in progress is attached below; it compiles and runs, but I cannot see any change reflected on the worksheet. I am considering some possible reasons, one of them is not using `offset` function when catching the relative cell when comparing the value in current row and the row above.

Thank you so much up front, and any advice/suggestion would be helpful! Sincere appreciation.

The code is as this:

```
Sub test()
Dim co As Long
Dim ro As Long
Dim ce As Range, works As Worksheet, lastro As Long, lastco As Long

Set works = ActiveSheet
co = works.UsedRange.Columns.Count
lastro = works.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastco = 5

For co = 2 To lastco
    For ro = lastro To 2
        With works.Cells(co, ro)
            If Range("A" & ro).Value <> Range("A" & ro - 1).Value Then
            .Value = works.Cells(ro, co).WorksheetFunction.Sum.Value
            End If
        End With
    Next ro
Next co
 
End Sub
```

Update on September 3rd, 2020

So I have gotten the results to be exactly what I look for, after consolidating from a previous answer gathered.

The functions were done in two separated steps: to rolling add everything to the last row with the same identification number, and then to delete every row except for the last row. There were criteria inserted to prevent over-deleting. Also, it is something taken out from a more comprehensive raw data table, so there can be some formatting that did not appear in the samples.

The codes look like these:

```
Sub cumulativeSum()

Dim colu As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    colu = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    
    Do While colu > 9
        For row = 7 To lr
            With ws.Cells(row, colu)
                If ws.Cells(row, "D").Value = ws.Cells(row + 1, "D").Value _
                And Len(.Value) <> 0 Then
                    ws.Cells(row + 1, colu).Value = ws.Cells(row, colu) _
                    .Value + ws.Cells(row + 1, colu).Value
                End If
            End With
        Next row
        colu = colu - 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Sum Completed"

End Sub
```

And the deletion:

```
Sub deletionRedundant()

Dim row As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    
        For row = lr To 7 Step -1
            If ws.Cells(row, "D").Value = ws.Cells(row - 1, "D").Value _
            And ws.Cells(row, "E").Value = ws.Cells(row - 1, "E").Value _
            And ws.Cells(row, "F").Value = ws.Cells(row - 1, "F").Value _
            And ws.Cells(row, "A").Value = ws.Cells(row - 1, "A").Value Then
                ws.Cells(row - 1, "D").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next row
        
        MsgBox "Redundant Entries Deleted"
        
End Sub
```

Just a collection here, and to discuss any improvement (to know what I don't know I don't know).

Thank you all for the helps from Ron, Foxfire and Jim when I initiated this question; please do let me know if I should post those as an answer or it is fine to update the question itself here.

Comment: Please allow me to correct a typo for "the last column belonging to the previous UID will be returning a sum of total numbers recorded for that UID in each column", the "last column" is "last row". Edit is done to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Just use a Pivot Table.  It will give you your desired final results.

Answer (score 0):

First, a bit of advice - you may want to consider having it make a summary sheet, rather than doing the edit in line, but that is just personal preference for risk reduction (that way, a bug won't hurt your original data).

Secondly, your thinking right now seems to be based on the idea that your data is sorted so that all instances of ID X will appear to be in a single group - I've kept that in the following code, but it seems like an unnecessary restriction.  At the very least, you will likely want to add a sort command to the beginning of the function to ensure that it is true - but I'll leave that to you.

Taking a look at your primary loop here:

```
For co = 2 To lastco
    For ro = lastro To 2
        With works.Cells(co, ro)
            If Range("A" & ro).Value <> Range("A" & ro - 1).Value Then
            .Value = works.Cells(ro, co).WorksheetFunction.Sum.Value
            End If
        End With
    Next ro
Next co
```

You don't appear to actually be aimed at what you are hoping to achieve - your goal is to sum all the rows with matching ID values (column A) and then wipe out everything but the summary.  You don't have a delete command or code to handle the situation for when the IDs DO match.

Try this instead:

```
For ro = lastro To 2
'invert your rows and columns here - iterate on columns inside of rows, not vice versa,
'as the rows are your driving characteristic
     if works.Cells(ro-1, 1)=works.Cells(ro, 1) then
            'here you are handling it if the ID row matches, vs not matching.
            'If they don't match, you can just move on, you are only trying to do 
            'something interesting if they match
            'Also, no need to iterate over the columns unless the IDs match, so put that
            'part of the for loop inside the if statement    
        For co = 2 To lastco
            works.Cells(ro, co)=works.Cells(ro, co)+works.Cells(ro-1, co)
        Next co
        'now you've got your current row summed with the row above
        'next, wipe out the row above - and you are still inside the If statement, 
        'so this only happens if they match ID
        works.cells(ro-1,co).entirerow.delete
        
        'now, because you are moving up from the bottom, and you just deleted the row 
        'above, if you immediately go "next ro" you are going to actually skip a row
        'so, jump ro back down (increase it by 1) so that you are still comparing your 
        'bottom row for the ID to the next row above.  If you don't like doing this, 
        'move from the top down instead of bottom up.
        ro=ro+1
    end if
Next ro
```

Comment: Thank you Jim! It seems I will take more effort to make the codes work, please allow me to modify and test it for a bit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way is, indeed, using Pivot Table:

[image]

Easy to do, clean and also easy to update

But  in case you want VBA code, adapt this one. It will create the resume in a new worksheet. It will use a Dictionary object to get the unique IDs, and then will SUMPRODUCT each criteria.

```
Sub TEST()
Dim wk As Worksheet, NewWK As Worksheet
Set wk = ActiveSheet 'the one that holds the data
Set NewWK = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add 'we'll create the data in a new sheet
Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long

LR = wk.Range("A" & wk.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'we get the unique values on a dictionary
Dim MyDict As Object
Dim MyKey As Variant
Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 2 To LR Step 1
    If MyDict.Exists(wk.Range("A" & i).Value) = False Then MyDict.Add wk.Range("A" & i).Value, 1
Next i

i = 2
With NewWK
    .Range("A1").Value = "ID"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Criteria1"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Criteria2"
    .Range("D1").Value = "Criteria3"
    .Range("E1").Value = "Criteria4"
    
    For Each MyKey In MyDict.keys
        .Range("A" & i).Value = MyKey
        .Range("B" & i).Value = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & wk.Name & "!" & "A2:A" & LR & "=" & MyKey & ")*" & wk.Name & "!" & "B2:B" & LR & ")") 'Column Criteria1
        .Range("C" & i).Value = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & wk.Name & "!" & "A2:A" & LR & "=" & MyKey & ")*" & wk.Name & "!" & "C2:C" & LR & ")") 'Column Criteria2
        .Range("D" & i).Value = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & wk.Name & "!" & "A2:A" & LR & "=" & MyKey & ")*" & wk.Name & "!" & "D2:D" & LR & ")") 'Column Criteria3
        .Range("E" & i).Value = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & wk.Name & "!" & "A2:A" & LR & "=" & MyKey & ")*" & wk.Name & "!" & "E2:E" & LR & ")") 'Column Criteria4
        
        i = i + 1
    Next MyKey
    
    'remove zeros
    .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End With


MyDict.RemoveAll

Set MyDict = Nothing
Set NewWK = Nothing
Set wk = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Best VBA code, consolidte ranges!!! Truly i think it's your best option. You can use consolidate due to how your data is structured:

> **[Consolidate data in multiple worksheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)**

[image]

```
Sub test()

With Range("H1") 'change H1 with destiny cell
    .Consolidate Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(, , xlR1C1, True), xlSum, True, True, False
    .Value = "ID"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found that the code was not working for me and still looking into the reasons. At the same time I will check Dictionary out!